# C# How to merge Two Dictionary with in user defined type excluding duplicates

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary, merge

```
class DataContainer
{
    public Dictionary<int, byte[]> bockedData { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
    ..
}
```

I Have

```
List<DataContainer> orginalReq;
List<DataContainer> gapReq;
```

I am trying to merge those two without duplicate keys in bockedData. Is this possible with LINQ ? Please help how to merge these two list.

edit:
console snippet for the situation:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<DataContainer> fromFist = new List<DataContainer>();
            fromFist = GetFirstreq();
            List<DataContainer> fromGap = new List<DataContainer>();
            fromGap = GetGap();
            //To Do Merge fromFist and fromGap with out dups



        }

        static List <DataContainer> GetFirstreq()
        {
            List<DataContainer> firstReq = new List<DataContainer>();
            Dictionary<int, byte[]> dict1 = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>();
            dict1.Add(1, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 });
            dict1.Add(2, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 });
            dict1.Add(3, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 });

            Dictionary<int, byte[]> dict2 = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>();
            dict2.Add(7, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 });
            dict2.Add(8, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 });
            dict2.Add(9, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 });
            firstReq.Add(new DataContainer() { BlockedData = dict1 });
            firstReq.Add(new DataContainer() { BlockedData = dict2 });
            return firstReq;
        }

        static List<DataContainer> GetGap()
        {
            //this can have dups
            List<DataContainer> firstReq = new List<DataContainer>();
            Dictionary<int, byte[]> dict1 = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>();
            dict1.Add(1, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 });
            dict1.Add(2, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 });
            dict1.Add(3, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 });

            //nedded data
            Dictionary<int, byte[]> dict2 = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>();
            dict2.Add(4, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 });
            dict2.Add(5, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 });
            dict2.Add(6, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 });
            firstReq.Add(new DataContainer() { BlockedData = dict1 });
            firstReq.Add(new DataContainer() { BlockedData = dict2 });
            return firstReq;
        }
    }

    class DataContainer
    {
        public Dictionary<int, byte[]> BlockedData { get; set; }
    }
```

I hope now this is clear.

Result May Like:

```
List<DataContainer> firstReq = new List<DataContainer>();
            Dictionary<int, byte[]> dict1 = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>();
            dict1.Add(1, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 });
            dict1.Add(2, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 });
            dict1.Add(3, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 });

            Dictionary<int, byte[]> dict2 = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>();
            dict2.Add(4, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 });
            dict2.Add(5, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 });
            dict2.Add(6, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 });

            Dictionary<int, byte[]> dict3 = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>();
            dict2.Add(7, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 });
            dict2.Add(8, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 });
            dict2.Add(9, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 });


            firstReq.Add(new DataContainer() { BlockedData = dict1 });
            firstReq.Add(new DataContainer() { BlockedData = dict2 });
            firstReq.Add(new DataContainer() { BlockedData = dict3 });
```

I Can get those Dicts Merged Like:

```
var gap = fromGap.SelectMany(o => o.BlockedData).ToDictionary(o => o.Key, o => o.Value);
var orginal = fromFirst.SelectMany(o => o.BlockedData).ToDictionary(o => o.Key, o => o.Value);
var final = orginal.Concat(gap.Where(kvp => !orginal.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the duplicate key? Which one would you like to keep?

Comment: Omit the duplicated and get a list of DataContainer back. Thats what my aim is. I dont need to omit any date in orginalReq but need to get the new data that is in gapReq.

Comment: So you have two lists of DataContainers, and you want to do something you call merge. Do you want to merge the two lists into one containing all DataContainers? Or do you want to merge all bockedData of all DataContainers into one dictionary?

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse Either of this would do, assuming that DataContainers BlockedData will not have any duplicate keys. Or merge all bockedData of all DataContainers.

Comment: I wish this could work:fromFirst.AddRange(fromGap.Where(kvp => !fromFirst.Contains(kvp)));

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify *Merge* very well.

- Do you want to merge the two lists of `DataContainers` into one list of `DataContainers` containing all `DataContainers` in the original to lists?
- or do you want to merge all `bockedData` of all `DataContainers` into one Dictionary? Of course this would only work if the keys of all `bockedData` in all `DataContainers` are unique.

The first one is easy:

```
IEnumerable<DataContainer> result = originalReq.Concat(gapReq);
```

Or if you want a list:

```
List<DataContainer> result = originalReq.Concat(gapReq).ToList();
```

The second method, put everything into one big dictionary, requires that you take all `KeyValuePairs` from all `bockedData` from all `DataContainers` in both lists as one sequence, and convert this sequence to one dictionary with the Key of each `KeyValuePair` as Key and the Value of each `KeyValuePair` as value.

In baby steps:

```
IEnumerable<Dictionary<int, byte[]>> allDictionaries = originalReq
    .Concat(gapReq)
    .Select(datacontainer => datacontainer.bockedData);
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>> allBockedDataRecords = allDictionaries
    .SelectMany(dictionary => dictionary.Cast<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>>);
Dictionary<int, byte[]> result = allBockedDataRecords.ToDictionary(
    record => record.Key,   // from every record take the Key as dictionary key
    record => record.Value, // from every record take value as dictionary value
```

Or in one linq statement:

```
 Dictionary<int, byte[]> result = originalReq.Concat(gapReq)
    .SelectMany(dataContainer => dataContainer.bockedData)
    .ToDictionary(
        record => record.Key,
        record => record.Value);
```